# Max Image Upload size Validation Django REST API

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework, image-uploading

I am using Django and Django Rest Framework. How to validate the image size of the image posted to django rest framework api ?

This is a bit confusing :

> FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = #something
>
> The maximum size, in bytes, for files that will be uploaded into
>   memory. Files larger than FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE will be streamed
>   to disk. Defaults to 2.5 megabytes.

I set this to 255 and even then I was able to upload a 2MB image from django admin. I want to reject the POST request and raise error if image size is larger than 5MB

Answer (score 11):

[FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#file-upload-max-memory-size) defines the maximum size a file can reach in memory before being streamed to disk. This is an optimization for uploading files. It **does not** limit the maximum file size that can be uploaded.

While this doesn't answer your question I hope it clears up your confusion about the setting.